# Gmail/Evolution "marked as deleted" go to archive folder (All mail)

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, evolution, gmail, email-client

When I click on the "mark the selected messages for deletion" icon, sometimes the email doesn't go to the trash. It goes to the "All Mails" folder in Gmail which is an archive folder. I'm using Evolution version 3.36.4-0ubuntu1. Does anybody know how to solve this?

This didn't happen with Thunderbird.

Thank you!

Edit: **Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS**

Edit 2: I switched back to evolution, and still the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04 and Evolution 3.44.4

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS